# Firebase + RxJava, onComplete() event

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java

Does anyone knows how to connect Firebase with RxJava so when I load ALL my data from database then it runs arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ?? 
I was thinking to write it in onComplete() method but it still runs before loading all data

```
        Completable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<cards>>() {
            @Override
            public List<cards> call() throws Exception {
                newUserDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUID).child("sex").exists()) {
                            myInfo.put("sex", dataSnapshot.child(currentUID).child("sex").getValue().toString());
                        }
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUID).child("dateOfBirth").exists()) {
                            int myAge = stringDateToAge(dataSnapshot.child(currentUID).child("dateOfBirth").getValue().toString());
                            myInfo.put("age", String.valueOf(myAge));
                        }

                        if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUID).child("connections").child("yes").exists()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child(currentUID).child("connections").child("yes").getChildren()) {
                                if (!dataSnapshot.child(currentUID).child("connections").child("matches").hasChild(ds.getKey())) {
                                    Log.d("rxJava", "onDataChange: " + ds.getKey());
                                    first.add(ds.getKey());
                                    getTagsPreferencesUsers(dataSnapshot.child(ds.getKey()), true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                return rowItems;
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        Log.d("rxJava", "Test RxJAVA, onSubscribe");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("rxJava", "Test RxJAVA, onComplete");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                        Log.d("rxJava", "Test RxJAVA, onError");
                    }
                });
```

and the output is

```
2020-06-04 23:36:28.797 29515-29515/com.example.tinderapp D/rxJava: Test RxJAVA, onSubscribe
2020-06-04 23:36:28.800 29515-29612/com.example.tinderapp D/rxJava: Test RxJAVA, onComplete
2020-06-04 23:36:29.018 29515-29515/com.example.tinderapp D/rxJava: onDataChange: a4hqGgAJBRTVJOlPp3blNDt5v7q1
2020-06-04 23:36:29.022 29515-29515/com.example.tinderapp D/rxJava: onDataChange: aA9HAOtaB7ao6vzKqqBNp0iaBev2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, this is expected behavior, which is described in the following:

> Completable.fromCallable

fromCallable takes a Lambda, which returns a List on subscription. In your case, a database-connection is opened as-well, which is basically fall through, because the callback is registered via callback non-blocking.

> subscribeOn

this makes sure, that the subscribeAcutal from fromCallable is called from given scheduler. Therefore the subscribing thread and and emitting thread are decoupled.

You get onComplete first, because the fromCallable will return rowItems immediately and the database connection will stay open, because you did not remove the listener. After a while you get data-base callback logs, because the database connection is still open and the listener is still registered.

You want to actually do something like this:

```
    Single.create<List<Card>> { emitter ->
        // register onChange callback to database
        // callback will be called, when a value is available
        // the Single will stay open, until emitter#onSuccess is called with a collected list.
        newUserDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent {
            // do some stuff

            emitter.onSuccess(listOf()) // return collected data from database here...
        }

        emitter.setCancellable {
            // unregister addListenerForSingleValueEvent from newUserDb here
        }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(
            // stuff
        )
```

If you want to have a constant stream of updates, exchange Single with Observable/ Flowable